# Fetch data from a url that loads result on scrolling

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to fetch all the data from the URL: https://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/General-Physician-Doctors/nct-10892680  but it only loads 10 results and when you scroll a little down it loads 10 more and so on...
What would be the best way to fetch all the results? I am only interested in the name, address, and phone number.

My Thoughts:

- Use Selenium and do web scraping. But the scrolling part could be challenging to implement and take time.
- I found a post request being made in the network tab when the new set of results gets loaded. But the parameters are changed every time, so I am unable to use the post request in the code

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code that simulates the Ajax requests the page is doing (maybe the HTTP headers needs to be changed `securityToken`, `requestsTime`).
Also, the results obtained from the server changes every time (but this is the same if you refresh the page in the browser):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = 'https://www.justdial.com/api/resultsPageListing?searchReferer=gen'

payload = {
    "area": "",
    "attribute_values": "",
    "checkin": "",
    "checkout": "",
    "city": "Mumbai",
    "darea_flg": 0,
    "lat": "",
    "long": "",
    "median_latitude": "",
    "median_longitude": "",
    "mncatname": "General Physician Doctors",
    "national_catid": "10892680",
    "nearme": 0,
    # "nextdocid": "022PXX22.XX22.191204000717.B8L5,022PXX22.XX22.220204115535.D1F1,022PXX22.XX22.220415212243.V7E2,022PXX22.XX22.150607231824.P4N6,022PXX22.XX22.190708170354.B2H8,022PXX22.XX22.211204121621.T8X2,022PXX22.XX22.180515101016.X1M6,022PXX22.XX22.131214171857.E9F6,022PXX22.XX22.190312214520.U6R2,022PXX22.XX22.140303130128.Q3Y4",
    "opt": "",
    "pg_no": 4,
    "search": "General%20Physician%20Doctors",
    "stype": "category_list",
}

headers = {
    'securityToken': '2a282a2b2f2b212a28282d',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0',
    'requestTime': '2023-7-3%209%3A20%3A05%20PM'
}

for payload['pg_no'] in range(1, 4):  # <-- increase the page numbers here
    data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload, headers=headers).json()
    for r in data['results']['data']:
        print('{:<50} {:<50} {:<15}'.format(r[1][:50], r[3][:50], r[15]))
```

Prints:

```
Dr Salaah Qureshi                                  Bon Bon Lane Juhu Versova Link Road Andheri West   07947159457    
Flashaid.in                                         Andheri East                                      07947234257    
Saroj Super Speciality Clinic                      Opposite Shabri Hotel Vashi                        07947169011    
Nahar Multispaciality Hospital ICU & Trauma Centre Davadi Naka Near Vyankatesh Petrol Pump Dombivli E 07947458296    
Sai Samarth Hospital Accident and Trauma Care Cent Mansarovar Station Road Kamothe                    07947337894    
Reshmi Clinic                                      Opposite Nitin Raj Hotel Kalyan East               07947213742    
Nikunj Physicians & Lifestyle Clinic               Next to Cloud 36 Ghansoli                          07947388155    
Saran Clinic                                       Nearby S M Shetty School Chandivali Andheri East   07947177897    
Dr. Kushal Mital                                   Opposite Nitin Company Flyover Next to Eastern Exp 07947174996    
V-Care Polyclinic & Diagnostic Centre              Near South Indian Bank Gokhiware Vasai East        07947241630    
Dr. Saloni Suchak                                  Opposite Hotel Manali Malad East                   07947162634    
Maxcare Hospital                                   Near Capital MallOpposite Railway Track Nalasopara 07947305957    
Sattvic Health Care                                Opposite Chembur Police Station Chembur East       07947365957    
Sai Samarth Hospital Accident and Trauma Care Cent Mansarovar Station Road Kamothe                    07947337894    
Nikunj Physicians & Lifestyle Clinic               Next to Cloud 36 Ghansoli                          07947388155    
Flashaid.in                                         Andheri East                                      07947234257    
Dr Aniruddha Chavan                                Opposite Paranjape Colony Virar East               07947172832    
Fortis Hiranandani Hospital                        Sector 10A Vashi                                                  
Metro Phoenix Multispeciality Hospital             Near Navapur Naka Opposite Bank Of India and Mahin 07947212171    
Apollo Clinic                                      Next to Holy Family Church Chakala Andheri East    07947177627    
Saroj Super Speciality Clinic                      Opposite Shabri Hotel Vashi                        07947169011    
Shree Ganesh Polyclinic                            Next to Ganpati Mandir Near Railway Station Dombiv 07947350902    
Sai Samarth Hospital Accident and Trauma Care Cent Mansarovar Station Road Kamothe                    07947337894    
Sanghvi Clinic                                     Near Vijay Sales Mukhi Nagar and Sai Baba Nagar Bo 07947168149    
Shree Family Health Clinic                         Father Agnel School AMBERNATH WEST                 07947185582    
Dr. Raskar's Diabetes Clinic                       Beside Image Restaurant In Front Of Roshan Petrol  08867893761    
Dr P M Kolge Clinic                                Behind Brahmand Phase 6 Brahmand thane West        07947471324    
Nakshatra Hospital                                  Andheri West                                      07947176733    
Joshi Hospital                                     Opposite Andheri Fire Station Behind Vijay Sales A 07947446397
```